# Get facing direction of BoxGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I get the facing direction of a BoxGeometry?

Or in other words, the normal of the "front" face.

I guess there's no way of knowing which face is the front face but I tried using `geometry.faces[index].normal` to get the normal of all faces but instead of getting the normal of the "outer" 6 faces of the box, I get all 12 faces, as if one side of the box has two faces in the opposite direction.

My idea was to make a circle around the box, with 360 points representing degrees and use a Raycaster pointing in the direction of the front face to find the intersection with the circle and get the orientation of the face in degrees.

Later I discovered that BoxGeometry has a rotation vector, that has the rotation in radians, but the problem is that it isn't a full rotation. For example a box rotated on its Y axis 45° clockwise is the same as a 135° but with different X and Z values.

Comment: Are you looking for the local direction (with respect to a parent object or group), or the world direction (with respect to the world coordinate system)?

Comment: Is your front face x or -x? Or is it perhaps on the y and z axis? Or could it be an arbitrary vector?

Comment: @pailhead I was basically going to go the "align any direction vector with the object's transformation" route once we know local or world. :)

Comment: I managed to get the normal vector of the face I wanted to know the orientation, and intersect it with a circle wich has 360 points to get the angle, but the weird thing is that the intersection has 12 points instead of just one.